# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#2-of ? extends IDto> to List<FollowingResponseDto>

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have an interface `IDto` and `FollowingResponseDto` implements `IDto`. I have a method that looks as such in a class called `AbstractController`:

```
protected final List<? extends IDto> findPaginatedAndSortedInternal(page, size, sortBy, sortOrder, uriBuilder, response){
    final Page<T> resultPage = getService().findAllPaginatedAndSortedRaw(page, size, sortBy, sortOrder);
    if (page > resultPage.getTotalPages()) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }

    return DtoEntityConverter.convertToResponseDtoList(Lists.newArrayList(resultPage.getContent()));
}
```

This is the code for `DtoEntityConverter.convertToResponseDtoList`:

```
public static List<? extends IDto> convertToResponseDtoList(List<? extends IEntity> entities) {
    List<? extends IDto> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();
    entities.forEach(e -> e.convertToResponseDto());
    return dtoList;
}
```

Finally, I have a class that extends `AbstractController`:

```
public class FollowingController extends AbstractReadOnlyController<Following> {
    @Override
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<FollowingResponseDto> findAllPaginatedAndSorted(
        final int page,
        final int size,
        final String sortBy,
         final String sortOrder,
        final UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        return findPaginatedAndSortedInternal(page, size, sortBy, sortOrder, uriBuilder, response);
    }
}
```

The call `return findPaginatedAndSortedInternal(page, size, sortBy, sortOrder, uriBuilder, response);` in the FollowingController gives me compilation error:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#2-of ? extends IDto> to List<FollowingResponseDto>`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Please note that the question remains why your internal methods use the interface and the method exposed publicly uses a concrete class. Usually it's the other way around. If at all possible I suggest changing the return type of `findAllPaginatedAndSorted` to `List<? extends IDto>`.*

---

You cannot cast from `List<? extends IDto>` to `List<FollowingResponseDto>` because the former can contain other types that implement `IDto`, not just `FollowingResponseDto`.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
interface I {}
class A implements I {}
class B implements I {}

List<I> interfaceList = ...;
interfaceList.add(new A());
interfaceList.add(new B());
List<A> aList = interfaceList;  // error! interfaceList contains a B, and a B is not allowed in a list of As
```

Now you might argue that there is no `B` in your scenario and that the `List<? extends IDto>` contains only instances of `FollowingResponseDto`. But your compiler doesn't know that and also there is no guarantee that this wouldn't change anytime in the future.

To fix this, you need to do the conversion yourself. Either do an evil in-between cast into `List<?>` or create a new `List<FollowingResponseDto>` and add each element from the `List<? extends IDto>` individually:

evil:

```
return (List<FollowingResponseDto>)(List<?>)findPaginatedAndSortedInternal(...);
```

not evil:

```
var idtoList = findPaginatedAndSortedInternal(...);
var followingResponseDtoList = new ArrayList<FollowingResponseDto>();
for (var idto : idtoList) {
    if (idto instanceof FollowingResponseDto)
        followingResponseDtoList.add((FollowingResponseDto)idto);
}
return followingResponseDtoList;
```

Comment: I guess the reason why I wanted to have the return type be concrete classes is just so its clear what is being returned while lookin at the controller. Is what I am trying to achieve not worth this visibulity?